# hiding div when scrolling taking effect unwanted width

Tags: jquery

Actually it must be simple issue, but I stuck at some point. `#div` is display none over 1000px width. and it displays when width is less then 1000px. So when it displays, I also tried to add hide it when scrolling.

```
var vw = $(window).width();

if (vw < 1000) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#div").css("display", "none").fadeIn("fast");
    });
} else if (vw > 1000) {
    $("#div").hide()
}
```

it's working. But one problem. Normally div is hidden when width is over than 1000px. But, if you make width less then 1000px and after that over than 1000px again. scroll function takes effect when width is over than 1000px I don't want it. I want hide the over than 1000px

I only want scroll function take effect width is less then 1000px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your if and your variable into the scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var vw = $(window).width();
  if (vw < 1000) {
    $("#div").css("display", "none").fadeIn("fast");
 } else if (vw > 1000) {
    $("#div").hide()
 }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. can I ask you one little question. How can I understand when page at top so display block a div?

Comment: when $(window).scrollTop() == 0 you are at the top of the page scroll